# Click Element to open Google Certified Shop Widget

Tags: google, widgets

There is a Google Certified Shop badge on the site that when clicked, slides in a Google Certified Shops widget on the bottom right.

How can I slide the widget in from clicking a different element on the site?

I have tried grabbing the class of widget and animating it's position but this resulted in nothing.
I have also tried to debug in Google Developer Tools and follow the functions but I can't find where or how this feature is triggered.

Can anyone point me in the right direction?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have recently learnt about the trigger() function in JQuery. This will trigger a different function based on an event.

Worked a treat for this issue.